# How to load images from gallery "images"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-intent-chooser, android-photos

I'm trying to load images from gallery using the following code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

The code works fine, however by default it loads only the recent photos. I have to click the menu to go to the "images" that show all images. Is there a way for me to load the image so by default it shows all "images" instead of the recent photos. Thank you.